# How to Speed up This Time Series Data Query?

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to query a small database, but even after 12 hours of processing time still no results. How can I fix this?

I've tried various forms of indexing including running the code through eversql.com

Here is the query: (lots of inner joins)

```
`SELECT
    bo2_b.[date],
    AD_B.[close] AS AD_B,
    BAX_B.[close] AS BAX_B,
    BO2_B.[close] AS BO2_B,
    BP_B.[close] AS BP_B,
    C2_B.[close] AS C2_B,
    CC2_B.[close] AS CC2_B,
    CD_B.[close] AS CD_B,
    CL2_B.[close] AS CL2_B,
    CT_B.[close] AS CT_B,
    CU_B.[close] AS CU_B,
    DX2_B.[close] AS DX2_B,
    EBL_B.[close] AS EBL_B,
    EBM_B.[close] AS EBM_B,
    ED_B.[close] AS ED_B,
    ES_B.[close] AS ES_B,
    FCH_B.[close] AS FCH_B,
    FDX_B.[close] AS FDX_B,
    FEI_B.[close] AS FEI_B,
    FFI_B.[close] AS FFI_B,
    FLG_B.[close] AS FLG_B,
    FSS_B.[close] AS FSS_B,
    FV_B.[close] AS FV_B,
    GC2_B.[close] AS GC2_B,
    HG2_B.[close] AS HG2_B,
    HMH_B.[close] AS HMH_B,
    HO2_B.[close] AS HO2_B,
    JAU_B.[close] AS JAU_B,
    JGL_B.[close] AS JGL_B,
    JPL_B.[close] AS JPL_B,
    JRU_B.[close] AS JRU_B,
    JY_B.[close] AS JY_B,
    KC_B.[close] AS KC_B,
    KPO_B.[close] AS KPO_B,
    LCO_B.[close] AS LCO_B,
    LC_B.[close] AS LC_B,
    LGO_B.[close] AS LGO_B,
    LH_B.[close] AS LH_B,
    MFX_B.[close] AS MFX_B,
    MP_B.[close] AS MP_B,
    NG2_B.[close] AS NG2_B,
    NQ_B.[close] AS NQ_B,
    RB2_B.[close] AS RB2_B,
    RS_B.[close] AS RS_B,
    S2_B.[close] AS S2_B,
    SB2_B.[close] AS SB2_B,
    SF_B.[close] AS SF_B,
    SI2_B.[close] AS SI2_B,
    SM2_B.[close] AS SM2_B,
    SSI_B.[close] AS SSI_B,
    STW_B.[close] AS STW_B,
    SXE_B.[close] AS SXE_B,
    S_B.[close] AS S_B,
    TU_B.[close] AS TU_B,
    TY_B.[close] AS TY_B,
    US_B.[close] AS US_B,
    W2_B.[close] AS W2_B 
FROM
    BO2_B 
JOIN
    AD_B 
        ON bo2_b.date = AD_B.date 
JOIN
    BAX_B 
        ON bo2_b.date = BAX_B.date 
JOIN
    BP_B 
        ON bo2_b.date = BP_B.date 
JOIN
    C2_B 
        ON bo2_b.date = C2_B.date 
JOIN
    CC2_B 
        ON bo2_b.date = CC2_B.date 
JOIN
    CD_B 
        ON bo2_b.date = CD_B.date 
JOIN
    CL2_B 
        ON bo2_b.date = CL2_B.date 
JOIN
    CT_B 
        ON bo2_b.date = CT_B.date 
JOIN
    CU_B 
        ON bo2_b.date = CU_B.date 
JOIN
    DX2_B 
        ON bo2_b.date = DX2_B.date 
JOIN
    EBL_B 
        ON bo2_b.date = EBL_B.date 
JOIN
    EBM_B 
        ON bo2_b.date = EBM_B.date 
JOIN
    ED_B 
        ON bo2_b.date = ED_B.date 
JOIN
    ES_B 
        ON bo2_b.date = ES_B.date 
JOIN
    FCH_B 
        ON bo2_b.date = FCH_B.date 
JOIN
    FDX_B 
        ON bo2_b.date = FDX_B.date 
JOIN
    FEI_B 
        ON bo2_b.date = FEI_B.date 
JOIN
    FFI_B 
        ON bo2_b.date = FFI_B.date 
JOIN
    FLG_B 
        ON bo2_b.date = FLG_B.date 
JOIN
    FSS_B 
        ON bo2_b.date = FSS_B.date 
JOIN
    FV_B 
        ON bo2_b.date = FV_B.date 
JOIN
    GC2_B 
        ON bo2_b.date = GC2_B.date 
JOIN
    HG2_B 
        ON bo2_b.date = HG2_B.date 
JOIN
    HMH_B 
        ON bo2_b.date = HMH_B.date 
JOIN
    HO2_B 
        ON bo2_b.date = HO2_B.date 
JOIN
    JAU_B 
        ON bo2_b.date = JAU_B.date 
JOIN
    JGL_B 
        ON bo2_b.date = JGL_B.date 
JOIN
    JPL_B 
        ON bo2_b.date = JPL_B.date 
JOIN
    JRU_B 
        ON bo2_b.date = JRU_B.date 
JOIN
    JY_B 
        ON bo2_b.date = JY_B.date 
JOIN
    KC_B 
        ON bo2_b.date = KC_B.date 
JOIN
    KPO_B 
        ON bo2_b.date = KPO_B.date 
JOIN
    LCO_B 
        ON bo2_b.date = LCO_B.date 
JOIN
    LC_B 
        ON bo2_b.date = LC_B.date 
JOIN
    LGO_B 
        ON bo2_b.date = LGO_B.date 
JOIN
    LH_B 
        ON bo2_b.date = LH_B.date 
JOIN
    MFX_B 
        ON bo2_b.date = MFX_B.date 
JOIN
    MP_B 
        ON bo2_b.date = MP_B.date 
JOIN
    NG2_B 
        ON bo2_b.date = NG2_B.date 
JOIN
    NQ_B 
        ON bo2_b.date = NQ_B.date 
JOIN
    RB2_B 
        ON bo2_b.date = RB2_B.date 
JOIN
    RS_B 
        ON bo2_b.date = RS_B.date 
JOIN
    S2_B 
        ON bo2_b.date = S2_B.date 
JOIN
    SB2_B 
        ON bo2_b.date = SB2_B.date 
JOIN
    SF_B 
        ON bo2_b.date = SF_B.date 
JOIN
    SI2_B 
        ON bo2_b.date = SI2_B.date 
JOIN
    SM2_B 
        ON bo2_b.date = SM2_B.date 
JOIN
    SSI_B 
        ON bo2_b.date = SSI_B.date 
JOIN
    STW_B 
        ON bo2_b.date = STW_B.date 
JOIN
    SXE_B 
        ON bo2_b.date = SXE_B.date 
JOIN
    S_B 
        ON bo2_b.date = S_B.date 
JOIN
    TU_B 
        ON bo2_b.date = TU_B.date 
JOIN
    TY_B 
        ON bo2_b.date = TY_B.date 
JOIN
    US_B 
        ON bo2_b.date = US_B.date 
JOIN
    W2_B 
        ON bo2_b.date = W2_B.date

`
```

I want a grid of various financial market closing prices in columns joined by date. Instead, I get impossibly slow query times unless I reduce the number of years of data to less than 2 (out of about 30 years)

Comment: Can we see your query plan please. https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/

Comment: I'm going to take a guess that your date columns are not unique and therefore you are doing the biggest cartesian join ever. But that is making an assumpiton and we'd be better of if you provide more info. What does the query plan look like (CTRL-L). Do you have indexes on all the join columns? How many records in each table? When you run your query for 2 years does the data appear as expected?